# Dilate/Erode: Difference between Step and Distance mode?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

What is the difference between the Dilate/Erode nodes Step and Distance modes? I can tell they are doing different things, but I'm interested in the technical details and the documentation does not cover it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Step and Distance mode, the Erode/Dilate node samples through all pixels and compares their value to the neighbouring pixels. If a neighbouring pixel has a lesser value, than it is matched the sample pixels value.

The following **pseudo** python shall demonstrate.

```
FOREACH a OF allPixels:
    FOREACH b NEXT TO a:
        IF (a > b):
            b = a
```

In **Step** mode, the adjacent pixels are right, top, left, bottom.

[image: dilate step mode]

In **Distance** mode, the adjacent pixels include diagonal connections.

[image: dilate distance mode]

Here is a comparison of an example.

[image: dilate step distance mode]